# How to read a file, Split the contents and print it?

Tags: java, println, split

i have a file named "file" which is a text file(the file contains 1,2,3,4 integers).. Now i want to read this file and split the values in the file and print each value in new line. How can i do that??

Comment: have you made an attempt to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: By programming, prefrable in java. Kidding: What have you done so far and what issues are you facing. This is not a "get my homework done forum".

Comment: i did try it many times. Infact i went through many questions on stackoverflow and various other sites, as i am a beginner i am not able to understand it properly. when ever i try to run it considers 1,2,3,4 as key and the output is "1,2,3,4= ". I am not able to split them

Comment: i did try to solve the problem many times but i was not getting the required output ... When ever i am running the program using files concept it takes  1,2,3,4 as a single key and the output is "1,2,3,4= " @akf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] str) throws Exception{

        File f = new File("C:\\prince\\temp\\test.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitedTokens = line.split("[,]");
            for (String splitedToke : splitedTokens) {
                System.out.println(splitedToke);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS a TON for your help. it works perfect. The above code of yours really helped me a lot..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void main( String args[] )
{
try {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("number.txt"));
  sc.useDelimiter(",");
  while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I tried your code but when i run the program it does not display anything.

Comment: Did you created file.txt?

Comment: yes i did create file.txt in the same folder where i saved the program.

Comment: Paste the content of file.txt and do you see anything in the output ant stack trace etc?

Comment: the file has values 1,2,3,4  the output was absolutely blank..

Comment: Sorry i missed ",". Please try with above code now.